# IF condition not acting well for all the cases

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am working on a module where a candidate appears for a quiz for 5 chapters. There are cases based on which a candidate can appear for quiz. If a candidate's quiz appearing validity date is over, he gets an alert box stating his validity is over and he is asked to send request to admin for validity extension. There are different conditions for which this alert box pops up. Now if a candidate has not appeared for any chapter's quiz till validity date and he requests permission from admin, and the admin gives him permission he can appear for quizzes. Here in this case even after getting permission for validity extension alert box pops up because he has not passed in any quiz. How can the given below condition be modified so that the candidate doesn't gets alert box even after getting permission whether he has passed in any quiz or not.
Here is my code and I am stuck in this condition only for the above said case.

```
 if((strtotime($today_date) >= strtotime($end_date) || ($pass_count == 0))) {

     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
     mess1= 'Your exam validity date has been expired. Click OK to request for extending your Quiz validity or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.'  

     x = confirm(mess1);
     if (x == true) {
         window.location = 'validity_request_mail.php?userid=$userid ';    

     } 
      </SCRIPT>");
 }
```

Help or advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `even after getting permission`-> how you come to know this for any user? which variable/value describe it?

Comment: When Admin allows extension, a status field is set to 2 which initially sets to 0 by default for all users and sets to 1 when the user requests. Thanks for concern

Comment: so that status is represented by `$pass_count`? is it?

Comment: No , I haven't used that status yet in the condition. The $pass_count counts whether the user has cleared any single chapter's quiz or not.

Comment: Then try to get that value in some variable and use that like below i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your permission as below. Suppose you have stored permission in `$status` variable.

```
if((strtotime($today_date) >= strtotime($end_date) || ( $pass_count == 0 && $status != 2) ) )
  {

 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       mess1='Your exam validity date has been expired. Click OK to request for extending your Quiz validity or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.'  

       x = confirm(mess1);
       if (x == true)  
   {
       window.location = 'validity_request_mail.php?userid=$userid ';    

   } 
      </SCRIPT>");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for concern . There is a status field which is 0 by default, 1 when user sends request and 2 when request is granted.

Comment: According to  $status ==0 condition, if the user has requested and set status to 1, then also the alert box won't appear?

Comment: Try my updated answer I have modified condition @Ansh

Comment: I am testing on this. Please provide me a few minutes. I will be back to you.

Comment: This works fine. Your time and effort are valuable and thank you so much for spending them on my issue. I hope this works well for all the conditions and I will thoroughly check on this. If any issue comes up I will turn to you. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand well your problem but I hope this will help :

```
if ($admin_has_given_access || $pass_count > 0 || strtotime($today_date) < strtotime($end_date))
    // Grant access
else
    // Redirect
```

Comment: Well this doesn't solves the issue but I am sorry for being messy in stating my problem. I highly appreciate your effort and time. Thank you so much.